# Check whether or not a query parameter is set

Tags: azure, query-string, azure-api-management

In Azure API Management, I need to check whether or not a query parameter is set.  To achieve this, I'm trying to use `context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault(queryParameterName: string, defaultValue: string)`.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ContextVariables), this expression works as follows -

> Returns comma separated query parameter values or defaultValue if the parameter is not found.

With that in mind, I used the example from the MS blog [Policy Expressions in Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/policy-expressions-in-azure-api-management/), to create the following `<inbound>` policy -

```
<set-variable name="uniqueId" value="@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("uniqueId", ""))" />
```

However, whenever I include this policy, execution fails with **404 Resource Not Found**.  Upon inspection of the trace, I can see that the execution was aborted without error before a single policy was evaluated (no matter where within `<inbound>` the above policy is placed.

This behavour results in the following `<backend>` trace, which explains the **404**

```
    "backend": [
        {
            "source": "configuration",
            "timestamp": "2017-09-07T12:42:13.8974772Z",
            "elapsed": "00:00:00.0003536",
            "data": {
                "message": "Unable to identify Api or Operation for this request. Responding to the caller with 404 Resource Not Found."
            }
        }
    ],
```

Given that the MS documentation seems to be inaccurate, how can I check whether or not a query parameter is set?

Answer (score 2):

So the answer here is that there is (another) MS bug.

When the API operation was originally created, the `uniqueId` query parameter was set as required.  I changed this so that it was not required before adding the policy described in my question, however a bug within the new Azure Portal means that when you uncheck the **Required** box adjacent to the query parameter and then save your changes, they are ignored.

I was able to work around this behaviour be editng the YAML template in the **OpenAPPI specification view**, removing the declaration `required: true` for the query parameter in question.  The expresion within my policy now works as expected.

***Please note:*** that this workaround sheds light on yet another bug, where saving the template results in your policies being deleted, so make sure you take a copy first.

Comment: Hey David, sorry for the pain.  I believe (but not sure) the issue is a little different than you describe.  The "required" property in the UI is currently just a documentation hint.  The real driver is the UrlTemplate.  I'm guessing that previously the uniqueId was defined in the query string of the UrlTemplate.  This is what made it required for operation matching.  I think that when you changed the OpenAPI description and saved it removed the parameter from the UrlTemplate.  Unfortunately, we use the path and method as the key for policies. Hence why they disappeared.

Comment: We have quite a bit of work to do on the OpenAPI editor in the Azure Portal.  It is made extra difficult because OpenAPI doesn't support everything we do, so round-tripping can be challenging some times.  Hopefully as we add support for OpenAPI V3 we can resolve issues such as these you have experienced.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for taking the time to post your question and actually provide your answer.

Comment: @DarrelMiller - Thanks for your replies.  I notice today that `uniqueId` is indeed listed under "Query", as opposted to "Template" as it was yesterday, so your suspicions were probably correct.  What whould be really great is if some tool-tips were added to the Portal to explain things such as **the "required" property in the UI is currently just a documentation hint**, because it's not at all obvioius and I can't find any mention of that in my (brief) review of documentation.

Comment: Completely agreed.  We understand that our documentation needs a whole lot of love.  We are trying to make that happen.  Please keep complaining about the docs.  It actually helps us.  I would also like to see that required property actually be enforced by APIM.